# Talend Build Job - Compilation issue

Tags: java, maven, etl, talend, tac

I have been using Talend Data Integration Tool (Licensed Version) in my company.But,since its license is too much expensive,we have been told to use Talend Open Studio (Free Open source version).So,we have to move all our existing jobs to Free Version's work-space.Some components are not there in free version,so I have used possible alternatives to achieve similar functionality.Now,I am trying to Build the job from Talend,I am getting compilation error of routine and I am not able to Build job to test.Can anyone help me out in solving this ?

I have tried to remove dependency(import package) from job's source file manually but every time I Build the job,it is automatically getting imported into the source code.

I am getting this error :

```
org.talend.commons.exception.PersistenceException: org.talend.designer.runprocess.ProcessorException: java.lang.Exception: [ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[ERROR] C:\Program Files\TOS_DI-Win32-20181026_1147-V7.1.1\workspace\MASTERDB\poms\jobs\process\Standard\GENERIC\Finalization_Scripts\is_golden_record\datablock_is_golden_record\company_identifier_is_golden_0.1\src\main\java\masterdb\company_identifier_is_golden_0_1\company_identifier_is_golden.java:[21] 
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[ERROR] C:\Program Files\TOS_DI-Win32-20181026_1147-V7.1.1\workspace\MASTERDB\poms\jobs\process\Standard\Factset\Automated_Jobs\factset_load_company_name_automated_0.1\src\main\java\masterdb\factset_load_company_name_automated_0_1\Factset_Load_Company_Name_Automated.java:[20] 
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.6.1:compile (default-compile) on project company_identifier_is_golden: Compilation failure
[ERROR] C:\Program Files\TOS_DI-Win32-20181026_1147-V7.1.1\workspace\MASTERDB\poms\jobs\process\Standard\GENERIC\Finalization_Scripts\is_golden_record\datablock_is_golden_record\company_identifier_is_golden_0.1\src\main\java\masterdb\company_identifier_is_golden_0_1\company_identifier_is_golden.java:[21]
[ERROR] import routines.TalendDataGenerator;
[ERROR] ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
[ERROR] The import routines.TalendDataGenerator cannot be resolved
[ERROR] 1 problem (1 error)
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :company_identifier_is_golden

    at org.talend.repository.ui.wizards.exportjob.scriptsmanager.BuildJobManager.buildJob(BuildJobManager.java:298)
    at org.talend.repository.ui.wizards.exportjob.scriptsmanager.BuildJobManager.buildJob(BuildJobManager.java:210)
    at org.talend.repository.ui.wizards.exportjob.scriptsmanager.BuildJobManager.buildJobs(BuildJobManager.java:125)
    at org.talend.repository.ui.wizards.exportjob.JobScriptsExportWizardPage.buildJobWithMaven(JobScriptsExportWizardPage.java:1491)
    at org.talend.repository.ui.wizards.exportjob.JobScriptsExportWizardPage$8.run(JobScriptsExportWizardPage.java:1394)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext.runInCurrentThread(ModalContext.java:466)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext.run(ModalContext.java:374)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.run(WizardDialog.java:1059)
    at org.talend.repository.ui.wizards.exportjob.JobScriptsExportWizardPage.finish(JobScriptsExportWizardPage.java:1399)
    at org.talend.repository.ui.wizards.exportjob.JavaJobScriptsExportWSWizardPage.finish(JavaJobScriptsExportWSWizardPage.java:1643)
    at org.talend.repository.ui.wizards.exportjob.JobScriptsExportWizard.performFinish(JobScriptsExportWizard.java:126)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.finishPressed(WizardDialog.java:853)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.buttonPressed(WizardDialog.java:438)
    at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog$2.widgetSelected(Dialog.java:619)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:248)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4353)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1061)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4172)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3761)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Window.java:832)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:808)
    at org.talend.repository.ui.actions.ExportJobScriptAction.doRun(ExportJobScriptAction.java:122)
    at org.talend.repository.ui.actions.AContextualAction$2.run(AContextualAction.java:673)
    at org.talend.repository.RepositoryWorkUnit.executeRun(RepositoryWorkUnit.java:99)
    at org.talend.core.repository.model.AbstractRepositoryFactory.executeRepositoryWorkUnit(AbstractRepositoryFactory.java:258)
    at org.talend.repository.localprovider.model.LocalRepositoryFactory.executeRepositoryWorkUnit(LocalRepositoryFactory.java:3495)
    at org.talend.core.repository.model.ProxyRepositoryFactory.executeRepositoryWorkUnit(ProxyRepositoryFactory.java:2265)
    at org.talend.repository.ui.actions.AContextualAction.run(AContextualAction.java:686)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.Action.runWithEvent(Action.java:519)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(ActionContributionItem.java:595)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.access$2(ActionContributionItem.java:511)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem$5.handleEvent(ActionContributionItem.java:420)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4353)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1061)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4172)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3761)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1151)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1032)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:636)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:579)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
    at org.talend.rcp.intro.Application.start(Application.java:265)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:380)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:235)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:648)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:603)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1465)
Caused by: org.talend.designer.runprocess.ProcessorException: java.lang.Exception: [ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[ERROR] C:\Program Files\TOS_DI-Win32-20181026_1147-V7.1.1\workspace\MASTERDB\poms\jobs\process\Standard\GENERIC\Finalization_Scripts\is_golden_record\datablock_is_golden_record\company_identifier_is_golden_0.1\src\main\java\masterdb\company_identifier_is_golden_0_1\company_identifier_is_golden.java:[21] 
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[ERROR] C:\Program Files\TOS_DI-Win32-20181026_1147-V7.1.1\workspace\MASTERDB\poms\jobs\process\Standard\Factset\Automated_Jobs\factset_load_company_name_automated_0.1\src\main\java\masterdb\factset_load_company_name_automated_0_1\Factset_Load_Company_Name_Automated.java:[20] 
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.6.1:compile (default-compile) on project company_identifier_is_golden: Compilation failure
[ERROR] C:\Program Files\TOS_DI-Win32-20181026_1147-V7.1.1\workspace\MASTERDB\poms\jobs\process\Standard\GENERIC\Finalization_Scripts\is_golden_record\datablock_is_golden_record\company_identifier_is_golden_0.1\src\main\java\masterdb\company_identifier_is_golden_0_1\company_identifier_is_golden.java:[21]
[ERROR] import routines.TalendDataGenerator;
[ERROR] ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
[ERROR] The import routines.TalendDataGenerator cannot be resolved
[ERROR] 1 problem (1 error)
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :company_identifier_is_golden
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but I can't use the comment option (for the moment).

**"So, we have to move all our existing jobs to Free Version's work-space."**

1. Did you manually move the files from your old workspace to the new Open Studio workspace?
2. Did you only export the elements (Jobs, Contexts, Routines, etc.)? With/without the dependencies?

[image]

3. Did you export all the Talend project(s) and import it/them into the Open Studio version?

[image]

I suggest you to use the third option, export then import the whole project(s), by means of the option dedicated.

Let me know.

Comment: I have used 3rd option only..Exported all jobs,routines,joblets,context,etc..(everything) from my project and imported them in Talend open Studio.(Since joblet is not available in free version,I have to create a seperate job for that purpose,which does not matter here  I think)

Comment: I have edited my answer to better differentiate the option 2 and the option 3. Did you update the Jobs by using the option just near to the export option icon?

Comment: I used the option shown in first image..(Export Items .... Select All ... )

Comment: OK. Try to export your project as a ZIP archive (second picture) and then import it. You can import ZIP archive projects in the first select projects window (just after opening Talend Open Studio).